# Who is updating my database?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sql

I have a custom solution (FARM level) which is deploying webpart to my site collection.
 This webpart has a textbox, which is writing to custom database (Nothing to do with content DB)

Now, while adding data to custom db, connection string is used. This string  has UserName and password in web.config file

Question is, if users submit data through textbox from webpart, which account is technically adding data in that customdatabse

1. Current logged in user OR 2. UserName from connection string?

Comment: Your db connection will always be in the context of the connection string... You could however get the logged in user and add it as part of your insert or update.

Comment: Ok, so logged in user doesnt need any kinda access on Database, if connection string User is doing all the stuff..right?

Comment: That is correct